# Fuzzy matching not working in retry until mechanism in karate

Tags: karate

Trying below example:

Given url Url
And path 'abc'
And header Accept = 'application/json'
And retry until response.external_list == '#notpresent'

Although the response does not have the field, the condition is never met by karate and it fails